# Implement adaptive video streaming in React native video

Tags: ios, react-native

I am implementing video streaming in a react native project on Ios. I am using [React-Native-Video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video) player. How can i achieve adaptive  video streaming quality in React Native based on changing network quality?

Comment: Did you get any solution of this?

Comment: Any Luck with the solution?

Comment: where you able to accomplish this?

Comment: This guy did a tutorial where he's streaming SoundCloud: https://school.shoutem.com/lectures/react-native-soundcloud-streaming-app-tutorial-part-2/ hope that helps!

Comment: any luck with the solution ?